# How to print an entity - CoreData

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, entity

i would like to print an Entity.

i have a JSON, i get the value, set them in my entity. Now i want to display my entity to see if it is well set, how ?

here is my code, it seems working, the NSLOG print what i want. cool.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dataToDisplay = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //récupération du chemin vers le fichier contenant le JSON
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"JSON" ofType:@"txt"];

    //création d'un string avec le contenu du JSON
    NSString *myJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];   

    //Parsage du JSON à l'aide du framework importé
    NSDictionary *json    = [myJSON JSONValue];

    //récupération  du total des Boxes
    NSDictionary *resultats    = [json objectForKey:@"totalBox"];

    //récupération du tableau de Boxes
    NSArray *listBoxes    =  [resultats objectForKey:@"boxes"];

    //On parcourt la liste de boxes
    for (NSDictionary *dic in listBoxes) {

        getBoxes *boxes = [[getBoxes alloc] init];
        boxes.nameBox = [dic objectForKey:@"boxName"];
        //renseingement du score
        boxes.priceBox = [dic objectForKey:@"boxPrice"];
        boxes.kindBox = [dic objectForKey:@"boxKind"];
        boxes.typeBox = [dic objectForKey:@"boxType"];
        //ajout à la liste
        [dataToDisplay addObject:boxes];

        //libération de la mémoire
        [boxes release];
    }

    NSLog(@"boxKind %@", [[listBoxes objectAtIndex:1] valueForKey:@"boxKind"]);
    //à ne pas oublier après l'allocation effectuée au début


    // TEST 
    NSManagedObjectContext *cxt = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *newBoxes = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Boxes" inManagedObjectContext:cxt];
    [newBoxes setValue:[[listBoxes objectAtIndex:1] valueForKey:@"boxKind"] forKey:@"kindBox"];
    [newBoxes setValue:[[listBoxes objectAtIndex:1] valueForKey:@"boxPrice"] forKey:@"priceBox"];
    [newBoxes setValue:[[listBoxes objectAtIndex:1] valueForKey:@"boxType"] forKey:@"typeBox"];
    [newBoxes setValue:[[listBoxes objectAtIndex:1] valueForKey:@"boxName"] forKey:@"nameBox"];


    NSError *err;
    if (![cxt save:&err]) {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
    }

    [myJSON release];

    NSLog(@"%@", [newBoxes valueForKey:@"kindBox"]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [newBoxes valueForKey:@"priceBox"]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [newBoxes valueForKey:@"typeBox"]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [newBoxes valueForKey:@"nameBox"]);


}
```

Comment: @Flink: Why u commented like that? I mean NSManagedObject is there that says it uses coredata.!

Answer (score 0):

Look for this method

`entityForName:inManagedObjectContext`:

Returns the entity with the specified name from the managed object model associated with the specified managed object context’s persistent store coordinator.

**Return Value**
The entity with the specified name from the managed object model associated with context’s persistent store coordinator.

This method is functionally equivalent to the following code example.

```
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[context persistentStoreCoordinator] managedObjectModel];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [[managedObjectModel entitiesByName] objectForKey:entityName];
return entity;
```

I hope u r not looking for something like this

```
NSLog(@"%@",[newBoxes name]);
```

Comment: ok, just to be sure, the code below the //TEST NSManagedObjectContext.... add the values to my entity right ?

Comment: I hv hardly worked on core data, but it seems... yes ur code add values to entity.